# jQuery: simplest way to check URL for a parameter and pass it to anchor href if it exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://example.com/index.php contains the following two anchor tags:

```
<a href="page1.php" class="hyperlink">Link 1</a>
<a href="page2.php?b=1" class="hyperlink">Link 2</a>
```

One or more parameters may be passed in the URL, eg. https://example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2

Using jQuery/Javascript, what is the simplest way to test for the presence of parameter *a* in the URL and append it to the hrefs in the above links if it exists, so they become:

```
<a href="page1.php?a=1" class="hyperlink">Link 1</a>
<a href="page2.php?b=1&a=1" class="hyperlink">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: [Here's a post on parsing url parameters with jquery.](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html)

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I was using some jQuery which passed parameters from the page URL to the links but the trouble was it seemed to compound them without regard for syntax, so for example you might get https://example.com/page1.php?a=1&b=1?a=1 - which is not so bad in this example but it caused problems with some other code

Comment: Thank you, nbwoodward. I understand the author's approach and rationale, and will play around with this to see if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client side the simplest is use the [`URL API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```js
var mainUrl = new URL(location.href);
// Won't work in this demo so hard code href
mainUrl = new URL('http://example.com?a=foo&b=2');

var paramA = mainUrl.searchParams.get('a');

$('a.hyperlink').prop('href', function(){
   var url = new URL(this.href);
   url.searchParams.set('a', paramA);  
   return url;
})
// set query params as text just for demo
.text(function(){
  return 'Query Params: ' + this.search;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="page1.php?a=1" class="hyperlink">Link 1</a><br/>
<a href="page2.php?b=1&a=1" class="hyperlink">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was didn't understand at first so I kept searching but this does exactly what I want.

Comment: Is there some reason you have to call 2.1.1?

Comment: Only because it is available in the stack snippet to add with a single click and they haven't added more recent versions to select from there

Comment: I see! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the logic of app design wrong. That is something you should do on the back-end of the web application; you check for the input parameters in the GET request and format the links hyper-reference accordingly.Also if you are going to be passing the value many times it may be easier for you to store it in the user session temporary environment (using cookies).

If you are using PHP (as I may guess by the file's extension) you can do that very easily:

```
<a href="page1.php<? 
    if(array_key_exists('your_key', $_GET) { 
        echo('?your_key=' . $_GET['your_key']) 
    } 
?>" class="hyperlink">Link 1</a>
<a href="page2.php?<? 
    if(array_key_exists('your_key', $_GET) { 
        echo('your_key=' . $_GET['your_key'] . '&') 
    } 
?>b=1" class="hyperlink">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you mean about the logic of app design.

The reason why I have to update the links in the DOM is that the anchor tags exist in a template which is enqueued by PHP but doesn't actually support it.

I am honestly surprised that I have not been able to find a jQuery extension which lets me define a variable from a parameter in the page URL, then add that parameter to any <a> tag with the class *hyperlink* in two lines of code without violating URL syntax.

I know it's not good design where you can avoid it but people must do it all the time...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regex, by the way as i can see you are using php so filter them with $_REQUEST

otherwise getting everything after the link in regex

```
var url = window.location.href
var res = url.match("/\?(.*)/i")
```

res should contain everything from ?getTO&otherget